# To find the using of sendgrid with react and dotnet with azure

Tags: reactjs, .net, azure

So I have my app created using create-react-app in Azure, but need to add ability to send mail once a Form is submitted. I know this cannot be done in my react app, but being away from backend work for a bit, I was trying to search for a tutorial or something online that could guide me and setting up some sort of Dotnet with sendgrid so that this UI can now process sending emails with my forms. Can any of you recommend some direction, tutorials, etc... to assist with this as I am not seeing things on the Sendgrid website for this.

I was trying to search for a tutorial or something online that could guide me and setting up some sort of Dotnet with sendgrid so that this UI can now process sending emails with my forms. Can any of you recommend some direction, tutorials, etc... to assist with this as I am not seeing things on the Sendgrid website for this.

Comment: Have you tried in anyway? If yes, In which approach did you tried?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

> Setting up some sort of Dotnet with SendGrid so that this UI can now process sending emails with my forms.

- Create an Azure Function that uses the SendGrid binding to send emails. You can then call this function from your React application using an HTTP request. Below is the code that works.

```
using Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker;
using Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.Http;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using SendGrid;
using SendGrid.Helpers.Mail;

public class EmailFunction
{
    private readonly IConfiguration configuration;

    public EmailFunction(IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        this.configuration = configuration;
    }

    [Function("SendEmail")]
    public async Task<HttpResponseData> Run(
        [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Function, "post", Route = "sendemail")] HttpRequestData req,
        FunctionContext context)
    {
        var emailData = await req.ReadFromJsonAsync<EmailData>();

        if (emailData == null)
        {
            var response = req.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
            await response.WriteStringAsync("Invalid email data");
            return response;
        }

        var apiKey = configuration["SendGridApiKey"];
        var client = new SendGridClient(apiKey);
        var msg = new SendGridMessage
        {
            From = new EmailAddress("your-email@example.com", "Your Name"),
            Subject = "Form Submission",
            PlainTextContent = $"New form submission:\n\nName: {emailData.Name}\nEmail: {emailData.Email}\nMessage: {emailData.Message}",
            HtmlContent = $"<p>New form submission:</p><p><strong>Name:</strong> {emailData.Name}</p><p><strong>Email:</strong> {emailData.Email}</p><p><strong>Message:</strong> {emailData.Message}</p>"
        };
        msg.AddTo(new EmailAddress("recipient-email@example.com"));

        var response = await client.SendEmailAsync(msg);
        if (response.StatusCode != HttpStatusCode.Accepted)
        {
            var errorResponse = req.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError);
            await errorResponse.WriteStringAsync("Failed to send email");
            return errorResponse;
        }

        var successResponse = req.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK);
        await successResponse.WriteStringAsync("Email sent successfully");
        return successResponse;
    }
}

public class EmailData
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public string Message { get; set; }
}
```

In NuGet Package Manager Console install the SendGrid NuGet package

[image]

- In azure marketplace there is a twilio sendgrid service create a sendgrid and provide the Email that need to be  trigger check below.

[image]

- It uses the SendGrid API key to authenticate with SendGrid and create a SendGrid client. It then creates a SendGrid message with the form data and sends it using the client.

**Check Reference:**

- [Azure Functions SendGrid bindings](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/blob/main/articles/azure-functions/functions-bindings-sendgrid.md)